# Enabling Aero effect in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, aero-glass

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 as a Workstation and would like to enable Aero Glass for some software development. Is there a way to enable Aero Glass on Server?

Thanks in advance,

NieAR

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this article on how to [Convert your Windows Server 2008 R2 to a Workstation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419005654/http://www.win2008r2workstation.com/win2008r2/themes):

> 1. Start the **Server Manager** and click below the category **Features Summary** at **Add Features**.
> 2. In the **Add Features Wizard** window check **Desktop Experience** and also accept to install the **Ink and Handwriting Services** when asked. Then click Next.
> 3. Review the Installation Selections and click Install to start the installation of the selected Features.
> 4. After the installation has finished, click the Close button and click Yes when asked if you want to restart your computer.
> 5. After the computer has restarted, review and close the Installation Results window and go to **Administrative Tools** in the Start menu and click **Services**.
> 6. Double click on the service named Themes, set Startup type to Automatic and click Apply. After the Startup type is set to Automatic click Start to start the Themes service whereafter you can close the Services Manager.
> 7. Download themes.zip (38,5MB) via [Mirrorcreator](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0VFQAD9L/themes.zip_links), extract it and run install(.cmd) to install the Windows 7 Default Themes. This step is optional as you can also download the themes you want from [Microsoft – Windows 7 – Personalize your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13768/desktop-themes-featured?ocid=w8_client_themes)
> 8. Right click at an empty spot of your desktop and choose Personalize. In the Personalization window click a theme or get a nice theme via the Get more themes online link. If you have installed drivers for your videocard you will now have transparent windows and you are able to use 3D Flip (<kbd>Windowskey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>)!

Comment: I'm running WinSvr2008R2 in a VM.  Some of the Aero features were not available for me even after following all of these instructions until I also enabled `3D Accelerated Graphics` on my virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the current answer, here's a guide with some alternative formatting and pictures (though the steps largely remain the same. Adapted from to [Enable Aero Desktop Experience in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-aero-desktop-experience-in-windows-server-2008-r2)

#### First, **Install Desktop Experience in Windows Server 2008 R2**:

1. Click Start > Control Panel > Programs & Features > Turn Windows Features on or off.
2. In the Features Summary section, click Add Features.

   - [image: Add Features]
3. Select the Desktop Experience check box.

   - [image: Desktop Experience]
     Install additional features if prompted
4. Click Install, you might have to restart your Windows computer.

#### Next, **Enable the Themes service**:

1. Click Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services.
2. Click Themes.

   - [image: Themes Service]
3. In the Startup type list, select Automatic and then click Apply.

   - [image: Startup: Automatic]
4. Under Service status, click Start and then click OK.

#### Finally, **Select an Aero theme**:

1. Right-click on the desktop & select Personalize.
2. Click Themes.
3. Under Aero Themes, click an Aero theme.

   - [image: Aero Theme]